# Variadic Recursive Template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, variadic-templates

I have a particular format that requires space delimited tokens with a final null terminator (the null is part of the output). I created a function to send a series of space delimited tokens to an output stream:

```
// C++ variadic template function to output tokens to a stream delimited by spaces
template <typename T>
void join(std::ostream& os, T const& arg)
{
  // This is the last argument, so insert a null in the stream to delimit
  os << arg << '\000';
}

// Join one, add a space, try again.
template <typename T, typename... Args>
void join(std::ostream& os, T const& arg, Args... args)  // recursive variadic function
{
  os << arg << " ";
  join(os, args...);
}
```

This works fine for things like `join(os, 1, foo, "THING", M_PI);`. However, I also have some tokens that need to be not space-delimited, like `join(os, "KEY=", val);`.

I tried to play with the arguments, thinking maybe I could stuff a `nullptr` in the argument list and use that to overload the method, skipping the space, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do that kind of overload.

Most of the questions on variadic templates I have seen are fairly old, before standards compliance was more ubiquitous. If this has been answered elsewhere, please point me to it. I'm using GCC 7.3.

Or, just tell me I am overly complicating what should be very simple. Maybe the variadic template is not the right hammer for this bolt?

Comment: They have different behavior, don't stuff them in the same function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Introduce a helper

```
template <typename A, typename B>
struct pack_t {
  const A& a;
  const B& b;
};

template <typename A, typename B>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, pack_t<A, B> pac) {
  return os << pac.a << pac.b; 
}

template <typename A, typename B>
auto pack(const A& a, const B& b) noexcept {
  return pack_t<A, B>{a, b}; 
}
```

Use it like

```
join(std::cout, "Hello", "World", pack("pi=", 3.14));
```

Complete code ([live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/UEjFuhdMAuKROanh))

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename A, typename B>
struct pack_t {
  const A& a;
  const B& b;
};

template <typename A, typename B>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, pack_t<A, B> pac) {
  return os << pac.a << pac.b; 
}

template <typename A, typename B>
auto pack(const A& a, const B& b) noexcept {
  return pack_t<A, B>{a, b}; 
}

template <typename T>
void join(std::ostream& os, const T& arg) {
  os << arg << '\0';
}

template <typename T, typename... Args>
void join(std::ostream& os, const T& arg, const Args&... args) {
  os << arg << ' ';
  join(os, args...);
}

int main() {
  join(std::cout, "Hello", "World", pack("pi=", 3.14));
}
```

Note that you can extend the helper to support more-than-two arguments by basing `pack_t` on `std::tuple` via aggregation or inheritance. For example,

```
namespace impl {

template <typename T, std::size_t... Idx>
struct pack_t {
  T v;
};

template <std::size_t... Idx, typename... Ts>
auto pack(std::index_sequence<Idx...>, Ts&&... vs) noexcept {
  auto v = std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Ts>(vs)...);
  return pack_t<decltype(v), Idx...>{std::move(v)};
}

template <typename T, std::size_t... Idx>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, pack_t<T, Idx...> args) {
  return ((os << std::get<Idx>(std::move(args.v))), ...);
}

}

template <typename... Ts>
auto pack(Ts&&... vs) noexcept {
  return impl::pack(
    std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>{}, std::forward<Ts>(vs)...);
}
```

Now, you can pack a varying number of arguments ([live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lbxkWxIJVS7gROSH)).

Comment: I like this because it reads more naturally. I'll try this at work tomorrow.

Comment: @jwm Updated `pack()` that supports a varying number of arguments :)

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you can select a special type to skip the preceding space; by example you can define a `no_space_tag` class or struct

```
struct no_space_tag {};
```

and add a `join()` version that intercept a `no_space_tag` object in second position (third, counting `os`) and doesn't add the space after the first (second) element; I mean

```
template <typename T, typename ... Args>
void join (std::ostream & os, T const & arg, no_space_tag const &,
           Args ... args)
 {
   os << arg;
   join(os, args...);
 }
```

so you can add a `no_space_tag` object in this way

```
join(std::cout, "KEY=", no_space_tag{}, val);
```

or also in this way

```
no_space_tag  nst;

join(std::cout, "KEY=", nst, val, ',', "KEY=", nst, val2);
```

to avoid to add the preceding space.

The following is a full working example

```
#include <iostream>

struct no_space_tag {};

template <typename T>
void join (std::ostream & os, T const & arg)
 { os << arg << '\000'; }

template <typename T, typename ... Args>
void join (std::ostream & os, T const & arg, Args ... args)
 {
   os << arg << " ";
   join(os, args...);
 }

template <typename T, typename ... Args>
void join (std::ostream & os, T const & arg, no_space_tag const &,
           Args ... args)
 {
   os << arg;
   join(os, args...);
 }

int main()
 {
   char foo {'a'};
   long val { 42L };

   join(std::cout, 1, foo, "THING", "M_PI");
   join(std::cout, "KEY=", no_space_tag{}, val);
 }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do. I tried using nullptr (std::nullptr_t) for this purpose, but I had some issues with compilation. I suspect that the order of template overloads (or my template specification) was the problem. Thank you for proving that my initial idea was doable.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this. The `First` parameter obliges you to pass at least one parameter, but I think this is justified.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <ostream>
#include <cmath>

template<typename First, typename ... Rest>
void join(std::ostream& _s, bool _sep, First&& _f, Rest&& ... _rest)
{
    _s << _f;
    std::array<int, sizeof...(_rest)> status{(_s << (_sep ? " " : "")  << std::forward<Rest>(_rest), 0) ...};
    _s << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    join(std::cout, true, "These", "are", "some", "args");
    join(std::cout, true, "These", "are", 4, "args");
    join(std::cout, true, "pi", "is", "a", "constant", "=", M_PI);
    join(std::cout, false, "KEY=", "val");

    return 0;
}
```

This prints

```
These are some args
These are 4 args
pi is a constant = 3.14159
KEY=val
```

Comment: @PasserBy Yes, I just realised there was a second part I didn't address, so I updated the answer